# Switch from pry to IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, pry, pry-rails

I have discovered Pry not so long ago, but there are several aspects of Pry I don't like

- Cannot start writing before all libraries finish loading
- Execution time of copy-pasted code is quite slow
- Copy-pasting will just stop after some time; I have to repaste from where it stopped (around 35 lines max), while it works perfect in IRB--in case it's linked, I'm using iterm 2 on macOS.

Is it possible to live switch between pry and IRB? I love pry when it comes to debugging, but when it comes to efficiency /copy paster, IRB is still top-notch.

So I'm looking for

- Either a way to spawn/return to an IRB console from a pry console
- Either be able to decide whether I want to start a pry or IRB console

(My context is running a rails console `rails c`)

Any hint? Maybe there's an environment variable that would let me pick one of both?

Comment: For copypasting it makes sense to use `edit` command to invoke the editor inplace in `pry`.

Answer (score 6):

You can start Irb from a Pry console session just calling `IRB.start`.

Comment: But I am losing the context of the Rails application ?